# Getting Error 000539 from Raster Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, raster-calculator, error-000539

I am new to Arc and 10.2 but can not seem to figure out why this won't work.

```
Executing: RasterCalculator Con(("SLOPE_SLO.tif"  >=  .015) & ("SLOPE_SLO.tif" <= .15,1,0)) D:\GEOG_480\Final2\RastCalSlope
Start Time: Tue Jul 29 22:24:21 2014
Con((Raster(r"SLOPE_SLO.tif")  >=  .015) & (Raster(r"SLOPE_SLO.tif") <= .15,1,0))
ERROR 000539: Error running expression: rcexec() 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in rcexec
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 3620, in BooleanAnd
    in_raster_or_constant2)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 47, in swapper
    result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 3617, in Wrapper
    ["BooleanAnd", in_raster_or_constant1, in_raster_or_constant2])
TypeError: expected a raster or layer name

Failed to execute (RasterCalculator).
Failed at Tue Jul 29 22:24:21 2014 (Elapsed Time: 0.02 seconds)
```

Comment: It looks like it's having difficulty finding your files. Are you doing this in ArcMap or ArcCatlog or python? Your syntax isn't correct.. Con(("SLOPE_SLO.tif" >= .015) & ("SLOPE_SLO.tif" <= .15),1,0) would be better.

Comment: Make sure your raster have defined spatial references. Because of this I was struggeling with the same Error eigther with raster calculator or math.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by @MichaelMiles-Stimson in his comment:

> Your syntax isn't correct..
>
> ```
> Con(("SLOPE_SLO.tif" >= .015) & ("SLOPE_SLO.tif" <= .15),1,0)
> ```
>
> would be better.