# Cause of ERROR 000539: Error running expression?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, terrain, error-000539

The following errors in ArcMap are preventing me from moving forward:

1) In Raster Calculator using "Aspect":  **"%DEM_Aspect%" <= 90 or "%DEM_Aspect%" >= 270**

> ERROR 000539: Error running expression: rcexec() 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "", line 5, in rcexec
>   ValueError: The truth value of a raster is ambiguous. Invalid use of raster with Boolean operator or function. Check the use of parentheses where applicable.

I'm using SRTM1N34W087V2, 11-FEB-00 (Void Filled) raster.

I'm attempting to use ArcMap to accomplish the same results done in the QGIS tutorial Lesson 3:  Terrain Analysis.

The lesson is found here:  http://manual.linfiniti.com/en/rasters/terrain_analysis.html

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suspect that your question is more likely to attract potential answerers if you can **edit** it to describe the first step on which are stuck in terms of what you are trying to do in ArcGIS for Desktop rather than referring them to a tutorial at another website to translate.  It may be useful background to say that you are trying to translate a QGIS tutorial but your question reads to me like "I got this far, can you finish the rest?"

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that @PolyGeo.  I restated my specific problem.  This actually leads up to the original one.  I didn't realize using Raster Calculator in the step prior (North Facing) was giving an additional error.

Comment: Thanks for updating but don't forget (from the [Tour]) that only one question should be asked per question.  At the moment you seem to be asking two which would make your question too broad for focussed Q&A.  Additional questions to your first can be researched/asked separately.

Comment: I've further updated the picture and limited my questions as well.

Comment: That's much clearer and more focussed now - thanks!

Comment: Can we get a screen shot of the actual expression that causes the problem? I think it springs from the boolean operator *or*, in rater calculator you should be using | as the or operator see http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000z7000000.htm but I can't be 100% sure without seeing the *exact* syntax.

Comment: @Michael I swapped out _or_ for |, but get the same error.

Comment: Shouldn't it be Con(("%DEM_Aspect%" <= 90 | "%DEM_Aspect%" >= 270),1,0)? Your equation is a boolean but you can't store that, you would use Con to make the boolean into a value (in this case 1 for true, 0 for false)

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson - perhaps a duplicate of your comment/answer at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108839/getting-error-000539-from-raster-calculator

Comment: Looks like it @PolyGeo. Essentially the same: you need to store a *value* in a raster, not a boolean.

Comment: @Michael I understand, however the same error persists still.

Comment: Is it one of the other two that's causing the error? There are three raster calculators there, is it possible that the error is occurring on one of the others?

Comment: I've removed all other raster calculators and still the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with this statement is the parenthesis.. [Compound statements need to be enclosed in a 'block'](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Building_complex_statements/00p60000000p000000/):

```
Con((Condition1) | (Condition2),True_value,False_value)
```

[image]

The correct syntax for the field calculation is:

```
Con(("%DEM_Aspect%" <= 90) | ("%DEM_Aspect%" >= 270),1,0)
```