# Using Raster calculator gives ERROR 000539

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, error-000539

I'm new with ArcGIS. I would like to do a calculate of NDWI. So I'm using Arctoolbox => Spatial analyst tools => Map Algebra => Raster calculator.

But when I'm trying to perform it, I get this error :

```
Executing: RasterCalculator "Float("LT05_L1TP_196030_19990113_20180215_01_T1_sr_band2.tif" - "LT05_L1TP_196030_19990113_20180215_01_T1_sr_band5.tif") / Float("LT05_L1TP_196030_19990113_20180215_01_T1_sr_band2.tif" + "LT05_L1TP_196030_19990113_20180215_01_T1_sr_band5.tif")" D:\Users\paulc\Documents\SIG_ZHM\NDWI\1999_01_13_NDWI.tif
Start Time: Thu Oct 24 15:42:34 2019
Float(Raster(r"LT05_L1TP_196030_19990113_20180215_01_T1_sr_band2.tif") - Raster(r"LT05_L1TP_196030_19990113_20180215_01_T1_sr_band5.tif")) / Float(Raster(r"LT05_L1TP_196030_19990113_20180215_01_T1_sr_band2.tif") + Raster(r"LT05_L1TP_196030_19990113_20180215_01_T1_sr_band5.tif"))

ERROR 000539: Error running expression: rcexec() 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 2, in rcexec
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from arcpy.geoprocessing import gp
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _base import *
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 598, in <module>
    env = GPEnvironments(gp)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 595, in GPEnvironments
    return GPEnvironment(geoprocessor)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 548, in __init__
    import weakref
  File "D:\Programmes (x86)\Python\Lib\weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref

Failed to execute (RasterCalculator).
```

How can I fix this?

I have already tried to change the wayfolder for a shorter way, without space or special character, but it's still like there is a problem with the wayfolder.

Comment: Just tried your logic and it worked for me. Have you seen [this](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011928) and may be [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142333/cause-of-error-000539-error-running-expression)?

Comment: ok just to be sure, i need to do a python script, and open it in argis to run it ? i'm a student, so i'm a bit stuck with the comprehension of this.

Thank you for your answear

Comment: I suspect the problem lies elsewhere, your equation is quite simple and should not be throwing an error. May be you have a corrupted install of ArcMap? May be there are network issues with your source datasets?

Answer (score 0):

Rename the bands for the ndwi. say band 1, band2, band3, and band 4. 
Open python IDE in ArcMap, and type in 
* img 1 = arcpy.Raster("C:/band1(Path)") - Do for img 2, img 3 and img 4 
* Ndwi =float( img 1 - img2)/ img 1 + img 2

This can be an alternative to raster calculator.